# OData support two routes which returns a single entity and a collection

Tags: asp.net-core, odata

I'd like to define two routes so I can access my entities. The code example below however returns an exception whenever I try to access my swagger.json file.

> Bad Request - Error in query syntax.

There are a total of 2 routes I need;

- /EventLog(MeetingId={keyMeetingId},Id={keyId}) -> Returns a single entity
- Search(MeetingId={keyMeetingId} -> Returns multiple records

Builder;

```
var eventLog = builder.EntitySet<EventLog<object>>(nameof(EventLog<object>)).EntityType;
eventLog.HasKey(x => new { x.MeetingId, x.Id });

var eventLogSearch = eventLog.Collection
   .Action("Search")
   .ReturnsCollectionFromEntitySet<EventLog<object>>(nameof(EventLog<object>));

eventLogSearch.Parameter<string>("MeetingId")
.Required();
```

Startup:

```
 app.UseMvc(
                builder =>
                {
                    builder.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ODataOptions>()
                    .UrlKeyDelimiter = Parentheses;
                    builder.Count();
                    builder.Expand()
                        .Select()
                        .OrderBy()
                        .Filter();
                    builder.MapVersionedODataRoutes("odata", "api", modelBuilder.GetEdmModels());

                    builder.EnableDependencyInjection();
                });
```

I've tried several other solutions, but they result in either a 404 or the error like above. Any suggestions on how to support both routes?

I'm using asp.net core 2.2

Comment: Please tell us ASP.NET Core version of your project, and please share the more/detailed code you are using to configure OData in Startup.cs

Comment: @FeiHan I've added a bit more details to my question.